# Form check with JS: select at least one checkbox and max 2 checkboxes

Tags: javascript, validation, forms, checkbox

is there a way to validate a form through JS and check how many checkboxes are selected?
I have a list with 15 checkboxes and I want that the user check exactly 2 checkboxes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if( $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length == 2 )
{
   //good
}
else
{
   //bad
}
```

Alternatively, use

```
$('myForm :checkbox:checked').length
```

Comment: can I specify a class for the checkbox?

Comment: I've solved: $('input[type="checkbox"][name=checkb_name]:checked')

Answer (score 1):

if you don't want to rely on jquery

```
    function exactly2() {
        var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
        var count = 0;

        for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
            if (inputs[i].type == "checkbox" && inputs[i].checked) {
                count++;
            }
        }

        return (count == 2);
    }
```

Comment: Give a man a bandaid, and he may be able to heal a wound. Give a man a doctor with full medical supplies, and the wound becomes an implementation detail. Not all cuts are solvable with bandaids.

Answer (score 0):

```
var amountOfSelectedCheckboxes = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length;
```